# C# - Gradually filling a rectangle using a timer and a trackbar to control the speed

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having issues trying to figure out how to fill a rectangle by using the trackbar value to control the speed of the fill. Imagine water flowing into a cup, so the water pours into the cup but the speed of the water flow is controled by the trackbar's value. I can't get it to fill from the bottom up. It starts from the top down, which I need it to fill from the bottom up instead. My code is below:

```
    private void trackBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        trackBarSpeed = trackBar.Value;

    }

    private void tmrTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timerCounter++;

        Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics();
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(81, 201, 219, (10 + timerCounter) * trackBarSpeed);

        graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(colour), rectangle);
    }
```

Comment: Winforms? WPF? (please add tag!)

Comment: Windows form, sorry my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create a new `Rectangle` in each timer tick. Instead create the rectangle once and modify its size in the timer tick.

Comment: I'm not sure how this actually addresses the question.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple issues with your current solution.

First, you shouldn't be painting your control outside of your `Paint` event. On your `Tick` event handler, you should update the rectangle you want to draw and then call `Invalidate()` on your control which will cause it to fire a Paint event and you can perform your painting in the `OnPaint` override. A `Graphics` object is provided for you in the event handler.

Second, a `Rectangle`'s position is the position of its top-left corner, so if you want to have the rectangle 'fill up' from the bottom, you need to adjust the location of the rectangle using some math.

Third, you should make a habit to properly `Dispose` of the `Brush` you create, ideally by putting it in a `using` statement.

The following is a LINQPad C# Statement which demonstrates these principles:

```
var label = new Label();

var trackBar = new TrackBar();
trackBar.Minimum = 0;
trackBar.Maximum = 10;
trackBar.ValueChanged += (s, e) => {
    label.Text = trackBar.Value.ToString();
};
trackBar.Value = 5;
trackBar.TickFrequency = 1;
trackBar.Width = 200;

var fillingRectangleHeight = 0;
var fullRectangleBounds = new Rectangle(40, 40, 100, 400);
var fillColor = Color.Blue;

var panel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
panel.Controls.Add(trackBar);
panel.Controls.Add(label);
panel.Paint += (s, e) => {

    var bottom = fullRectangleBounds.Bottom;
    var top = bottom - fillingRectangleHeight;
    var fillingRectangleBounds = new Rectangle(
        fullRectangleBounds.X, top, fullRectangleBounds.Width, fillingRectangleHeight);

    using (var fillBrush = new SolidBrush(fillColor))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(fillBrush, fillingRectangleBounds);
    }

};

var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer.Interval = 1000;
timer.Tick += (s, e) => {

    fillingRectangleHeight = Math.Min(
        fillingRectangleHeight + trackBar.Value, 
        fullRectangleBounds.Height);
    panel.Invalidate();

    if (fillingRectangleHeight == fullRectangleBounds.Height)
    {
        // once the rectangle is full, no point in the timer
        // running anymore
        timer.Stop();
    }

};
timer.Start();

panel.Dump();
```